# Tell to OpenShift to use Kubernetes in a specific folder

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-origin

I have to use a version of Kubernetes by me but I don't know how to tell to OpenShift to use that version of Kubernetes.
At the beginning I thought that I have to recompile the source code of OpenShift Origin and I did it. So, do someone tell me how to configure OpenShift to do what I explained above?
I use CentOS 7 on a CloudStack virtual machine.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenShift can either run its own compiled-in Kubernetes components (which is the typical setup), or can run against an external Kubernetes server process. It does not manage launching an external Kubernetes binary.

You can run OpenShift against an external Kubernetes process by giving the OpenShift master a kubeconfig file containing connection information and credentials for an existing Kubernetes API server:

```
openshift start master --kubeconfig=/path/to/k8s.kubeconfig
```

Comment: there are a couple issues open currently related to running against an external Kubernetes process (https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/8124 and https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/8110)